# error waiting for one function to complete before executing an action dart

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

Am trying to push in a new page after I have checked if the returned user uid is not null.I think the problem is that by the time the page is pushed the user uid is always null.so it always push to the error page.How do I fix this or is there a better way to achueve similar results from what an trying to do

```
    Future<FirebaseUser> signInUser([var myuserdata,var mypasswrd
      ,frouter,srouter]
      )async{
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:myuserdata,password:mypasswrd).then((onValue){
          if(onValue.uid != null){
// main page
        print('object at non-null uid ${onValue.uid}');
        frouter;
      } 
     if(onValue.uid == null){
//error page
        srouter;
      print('object at null uid ${onValue.uid}');
      } 
      });
      print('user id :${firebaseUser.uid}');
    return firebaseUser;
    }
```

`Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid`

`I/flutter ( 8462): object at non-null uid q0q9vYK7AsPBrVpRQUwH04jyCp22`

Comment: Basically, you are doing both `await` and `callback` (.then). Either remove `await` and go with callback or remove `callback` and use as @John Wick suggested

Answer (score 0):

There seems to some problem with async handling in your code.
Try this one hope it helps.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> signInUser([var myuserdata,var mypasswrd
      ,frouter,srouter]
      )async{

      FirebaseUser firebaseUser =  
               await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email:myuserdata,password:mypasswrd);

       if(firebaseUser .uid != null){
        // main page
        print('object at non-null uid ${onValue.uid}');
        frouter;
       } 
       else if(firebaseUser .uid == null){
        //error page
        srouter;
        print('object at null uid ${onValue.uid}');
       } 
      });
      print('user id :${firebaseUser.uid}');
    return firebaseUser;
    }
```